# Don't show video viewer UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm launching the Photo Library using the following code:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Upon selecting a video from my photo library, instead of the `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` function being called, it goes to a view that allows me to play the video with a video scrubber at the top. Then I press choose and it calls that function. How can I skip showing the view that allows me to play the video?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that while using `.photoLibrary` as source type, it is not possible to skip that part.

You can skip while making source type as **camera** and writing this:

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
```

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157755/skip-uiimagepickercontroller-preview-view) for more details